# POLYBASE ODBC getting Optional feature not implemented

Tags: polybase, sql-server-2019

While trying to get a connection to a sybase database via Polybase using ODBC, i always get the following error:

105082;Generic ODBC error: [SAP][ASE ODBC Driver]Optional feature not implemented .

Is there a way do get more detailed logs, or did i miss something?

Comment: When are you getting this error, i.e. when creating external table, or trying to do a ~SELECT`. Is this from SQL 2019 on Windows, or Linux?

Comment: When creating the table.